# Relationship between the inverse of the right eigenvector of a matrix $A$ and the transpose of the right eigenvector of $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, data-analysis, eigenfunctions

I should start by stating that this question is related to the Koopman's theory in dynamical system, which gathers growing interests in the fluid dynamics/data science areas such as dynamic mode decomposition (DMD).

Suppose $A$ has the eigen decomposition $P_1DP_1^{-1}$ where the columns of $P_1$ are the right eigenvectors of $A$. Then $A^{\text{T}}$ has an eigen decomposition $P_2DP_2^{-1}$ where columns of $P_2$ are the right eigenvectors of $A^{\text{T}}$. We can write down these relations explicitly
\begin{align}
AP_1&=P_1D\,,\\
A^{\text{T}}P_2&=P_2D\,.
\end{align}
From these equations, there are two ways of getting the left eigenvectors, namely
\begin{align}
P_1^{-1}A&=DP_1^{-1}\,,\\
P_2^{\text{T}}A&=DP_2^{\text{T}}\,.
\end{align}
Therefore, the rows in both $P_1^{-1}$ and $P_2^{\text{T}}$ are the left eigenvectors of $A$, but $P_1^{-1}\neq P_2^{\text{T}}$ in general. I believe
\begin{equation}
P=aP_1^{-1}+bP_2^{\text{T}}\,,
\end{equation}
is also a left eigenvector of $A$ for any scalars $a$ and $b$ that are not both zeros.

My questions are why the matrix $P$ is singular for $a=-b$ even though they are not equal (my guess is something to do with linear dependency), and what is the relationship between $P_1^{-1}$ and $P_2^{\text{T}}$ since both were derived using valid approaches for finding the left eigenvectors of the matrix $A$.

I asked this question because the Koopman eigenfunction is found by multiplying the left eigen vectors of the Koopman operator with its invariant subspace (linear variables derived from the original nonlinear variables). And I wish to understand whether the approach for obtaining the left eigenvectors of the Koopman operator matters in terms of the final Koopman eigenfunction.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is that there are many possible choices for $P_1$ and $P_2$, and the particular choice that you make impacts whether or not we have $P_1^{-1} = P_2^T$ and for which values of $a,b$ (if any) it holds that $aP_1^{-1} + bP_2^T$ is singular. We would need more information about how the matrices $P_k$ are being produced in order for this problem to make sense. For instance, is it necessarily the case that the columns of $P_1$ and/or $P_2$ are unit-vectors?